# Is there a way to get pairwise identifier of Azure AD User

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I am trying to perform SSO integration b/w Oracle cloud application and Azure AD using OpenID Connect.

In the jwt token response, the "sub" claim has pairwise identifier and Oracle uses "sub" claim to validate the user. So I will have to store pairwise identifier for respective user in Oracle cloud.

Microsoft documentation does not provide information about how pairwise identifier can be extracted in Azure portal. Is there a way to locate the identifier in Azure portal or any other way?

Comment: Jon Wang - Thanks for the suggestion, I am aware of this work around. As we are migrating all users to cloud, this will take more effort. Is there a way to calculate the pairwise identifier based on Client ID and User Object ID (or any other IDs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not get it directly in the portal, the pairwise identifier is unique to a particular application ID. If a single user signs into two different apps using two different client IDs, those apps will receive two different values for the subject claim.
More details, see [id_token Payload claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#payload-claims).

If you want to get the `sub` claim, use the [OpenID Connect protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#send-the-sign-in-request) to login with the user account and retrieve the `id_token`, then decode it in https://jwt.io/, store the `sub` for the specific application.

[image]

Comment: Jon Wang - Thanks for the suggestion, I am aware of this work around. As we are migrating all users to cloud, this will take more effort. Is there a way to calculate the pairwise identifier based on Client ID and User Object ID (or any other IDs)

Comment: @YashwanthS I suppose there is no such way.